# Calling function through iterator fails to compile on derived object

Tags: c++

I want to pass a pointer to a class method and call that function from an iterator. The code below fails to compile when I include a derived object.
I've tried using a typename for the class specifier (e.g. TC::*pf) but this doesn't work. Can someone suggest how to make this work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

class Base {

public:

  Base(int bval) : bval_(bval) { }

  virtual void print() {
    cout << "Base: bval:" << bval_ << endl;
  }

protected:
  int bval_;
};

class Derived : public Base {

  Derived(int bval, int dval) : Base(bval), dval_(dval) { }

  virtual void print() {
    cout << "Derived: bval:" << bval_ << " dval:" << dval_ << endl;
  }

private:
  int dval_;
};

typedef vector<Base*>       MyVecType;
typedef MyVecType::iterator MyVecTypeIter;

template <typename T>
void testFunc(MyVecType& v, T (Base::*pf)()) {

  for (MyVecTypeIter iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); ++iter) {
    ((*iter)->*pf)();
  }

}


int main() {

  MyVecType bvec;

  bvec.push_back(new Base(44));
  bvec.push_back(new Base(55));

  // above compiles and runs ok, but this fails to compile
  // with 'no matching function' error:
  bvec.push_back(new Derived(66));

  testFunc(bvec, &Base::print);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: You don't have constructor of `Derived` with a single parameter (neither public nor private)... Compiler error gives a big hint it is really worth reading :)

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 1):

line

```
bvec.push_back(new Derived(66));
```

does not compiler because Derived class constructor is private and is defined to take two int arguments.

Fix that and it will compile and run:

http://cpp.sh/9nrkc

Comment: Thanks - I actually messed up my question. It was a different error I had meant to post. It was if there's a way to use the above code on a method which is only in the derived class. The only way I can get it to work is having some default implementation in the base class, which I'd rather not do but don't know if there's any way around it.

Comment: You can also use a pure virtual function on base class to make it abstract and force derived classes to implement it.